# Python attribute name with a variable in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

I am making a desktop programm with Qt+Python and currently I am facing a problem calling some attributes with variable in their names

```
self.checkBox_Answer1.clear()
self.checkBox_Answer2.clear()
self.checkBox_Answer3.clear()
self.checkBox_Answer4.clear()
```

Number is the variable, so I want something like

```
self."checkBox_Answer%d" % (A).clear()
```

where "A" is my variable which is counted, but coding this way doesnt work

Also tried

```
self.str("checkBox_Answer"+"%d" % (A)).clear()  
self.checkBox_Answer+"%d" % (A).clear()
```

and nothing works

I know I can do something like

```
if A == 1:
    self.checkBox_Answer1.clear()
if A == 2:
    self.checkBox_Answer2.clear()
if A == 3:
    self.checkBox_Answer3.clear()
if A == 4:
    self.checkBox_Answer4.clear()
```

But isn't there more pythonic way to do this stuff?

Comment: yes stick your checkBox answers in a dictionary where the keys are `Answer1`, `Answer2`, etc...

Comment: did u try using .format() Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the name of the attribute using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). It will affect your performance but it's a cleanest way than a map.

It will looks like:

```
getattr(self, "checkBox_Answer"+"%d" % (A))
```

Comment: Thanks! Woked as I wanted it to work
`getattr(self, "checkBox_Answer"+"%d" % (A)).setText(buf[buf.find(")")+1:])`

Answer (score 0):

I would store these variables in a list:

```
self.checkboxAnswers = [checkBox_Answer1,etc...]

self.checkboxAnswers[A].clear()
```

You can access these variables in the list by using A. Note that lists start at index 0, so you'll have to increment A by one.